# useReducer. Dispatch is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my example when I click button I have error "dispatch is not a function".
Please tell my why? How correct set dispatch in props? Do I need always use useContext for that?

[source (codesandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-4lt4s-4lt4s?file=/src/App.tsx)

App.tsx

```
const counterReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state + 1;
    case "DECREMENT":
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const [counter, dispatch] = useReducer(counterReducer, 1);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CounterView counter={counter} />
      <Buttons dispatch={dispatch} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

CounterView.tsx

```
export const CounterView = ({ counter }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter: {counter}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Buttons.tsx

```
export const Buttons = (dispatch) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch("INCREMENT")}>
        +1
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch("DECREMENT")}>
        -1
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: destructure dispatch ``` export const Buttons = ({dispatch}) => { ...``` in Button component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `dispatch` as props but in this button component you calling direct variable. So you need get the props of dispatch like below

```
export const Buttons = ({dispatch}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch("INCREMENT")}>
        +1
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch("DECREMENT")}>
        -1
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Dispatch is passed in the props.

```
export const Buttons = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => props.dispatch("INCREMENT")}>
        +1
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => props.dispatch("DECREMENT")}>
        -1
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

or

```
export const Buttons = ({dispatch}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch("INCREMENT")}>
        +1
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch("DECREMENT")}>
        -1
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```